# ActiveMQ producer needs to know when consumer has started

Tags: activemq-classic

I am a newcomer, and I have a question I want to ask for your help. In my project I used ActiveMQ to implement communication. Now there is a requirement that the producer needs to sense whether the consumer has started, and how should I implement it?

Comment: Welcome, please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Message producers and consumers are decoupled by design. In other words, the producer doesn't care about the consumers and the consumers don't care about the producers. In fact, this is generally held as a fundamental tenet of messaging and cited as one of its major benefits. Therefore, ActiveMQ is designed with this in mind and doesn't provide an easy-to-use mechanism for clients to discover each other. I recommend you change your application so this isn't a requirement if it all possible.

Answer (score 0):

As others have chimed in, it is best to not have producers and consumers know about each other. Essentially, that is one of the primary benefits of event-driven-design-- applications are decoupled at *runtime*.

If there is some hard-and-fast rule to have producers and consumers communicate, then you can implement a communication channel using a dedicated Queue or Topic to send events. This design has a number of names-- side-channel, control channel or out-of-band communication.